# Backbone.js model.save() issues with a RESTful api

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model that I save to a database using an api. My problem is when updating this model. The first time I change anything and call model.save, the attributes get passed as JSON to the api, which parses it and saves it without an issue. Now, the second time I make a change to that model in the same view, model.save adds an undefined object to my model. The api sees this object and rejects the PUT request.

Why does it work with the first update and not the second one?

Thanks for helping.

Here is the code, I hope you can understand it.

```
var LDAccount = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        ACC_NUM : '',
        BOOK_DATE : '',
        F_NAME : ''
    },
    template : _.template(
        "<p>Full Name</p><input data-id='F_NAME' type=text value='<%= F_NAME %>' />" +
        "<p>Book Date</p><input data-id='BOOK_DATE' type=text value='<%= BOOK_DATE %>' />"
    ),
    urlRoot : 'api/account'
});

var LDAccountView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '', // set this when instantiating this model in the router
    initialize : function(options) {
        this.model = options.model;
        this.model.id = options.id;
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('error', this.renderError, this);
    },
    render : function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.model.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        $(this.el).append(
            '<div id="model_buttons" >' +
            '<input type=button id=reset value=Reset />' +
            '<input type=button id=save value=Save />' +
            '</div>'
        );
        return this;
    },
    events : {
        'click #save' : 'save2db'
    },
    save2db : function() {
        var $fields = $(this.el).find('input[type=text]');
        var modObj = new Object();
        $fields.each(function() {
            var $field = $(this);
            var prop = $field.attr('data-id');
            var val = $field.val();
            modObj[prop] = val;
        });
        this.model.set(modObj);
        console.log(modObj);
        this.model.save({
            success : function() {
                self.reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
    renderError : function() {
        $(this.el).append('<p class=error>Account does not exist</p>');
    },
    reset : function() {
    }
});

var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // code omitted since it's not relevant to the question
});

var LDRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "account/:modl/:acc_num": "renderView" 
    },

    initialize : function() {
        this.search = new MainView({ el : '#main'});
    },

    // THIS IS THE VIEW THAT RENDERS THE MODEL
    renderView : function(modl, acc_num) {
        var self = this;
        var model = null;

        switch(modl) {
            case 'account':
                model = new LDAccount();
                break;
            // these other models were omitted for clarity
            case 'asset':
                model = new LDAsset();
                break;
            case 'info':
                model = new LDInfo();
                break;
            default:
                model = new LDAccount();
                break;
        }

        this.account = new LDAccountView({ id : acc_num, el : '#accDetail', model : model });
        this.account.reset = function() {
            self.renderView(modl,acc_num);
        };
        this.account.model.fetch();
    },

    accountInfo : function (acc_num) {
        var root = '';
        var url = window.location.href;
        var hashPos = url.indexOf('#');
        if(hashPos != -1) {
            root = url.substr(0,hashPos);
        } else {
            root = url;
        }
        window.location = root + "#account/account/" + acc_num;
    }

});

$(function() {
    var app = new LDRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Comment: Adding some example code to give additional info on what you're doing would really help out.

Comment: Please add the code for model and how you save it.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
Passing all arguments to model.save seems to work.
In other worlds,

```
this.model.save(
    {
        success: function() {
            // do some stuff here
        },
        error: function() {
            // do other stuff here
        }
    }
);
```

solved the issue I was having.
I still wonder why save was passing an undefined object that was added to the model attributes.

Comment: Still wonder that this will work as the api says, the first paramater is a hash of atributes you wanna change on your model, and the second parameter are the callbacks. So `.save({}, {success: function})`, should do what you expected. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save

Comment: Andreas is right. The first parameter can replace `this.model.set('someProperty','someValue')` code. If you've already set your model properties (like the OP did), you can simply pass in an empty object, as Andreas indicates above.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you forgot to initialize variable, which stores POST data parts, with '' for example. So when data is appended to your variable as string it appends to 'undefined'. Resolution: the problem is in your server!